# jQuery wrapAll children if they dont already have a parent with certain class

Tags: jquery

Im using the following to wrap all items with a class of 'child' with a div with a class of 'parent':

```
$(".child").wrapAll('<div class="parent" />');
```

The issue is that the function is sometimes rerun and I dont want multiple div.parents' to be created. How can I add a condition to my code so the div.parent is only added if div.childs' dont already have a parent with a class of 'parent'? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) like this:

```
if (! $(".child").parent().hasClass('parent')){
   $(".child").wrapAll('<div class="parent" />');
}
```

Or using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) with `length`:

```
if (! $(".child").closest('.parent').length){
   $(".child").wrapAll('<div class="parent" />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know is it fast:

```
$(":not(.parent) > .child").wrapAll('<div class="parent" />');
```

**not tested!! but may work**

Answer (score 0):

Your can do it in single row )

$(".child").parents('p:not(.parent)').find(".child").wrapAll('');